# Plotting Errorbars from different DataFrame into SubPlots with matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

i just stumpled upon a problem I simply cannot solve. I have a dataset with raw data which I will upload here: https://file.io/oJqkZjAGyqV1
Its an excel file with the data inside.
I then created some code to open it, read it, generate a mean and sem of my data as below.

```
# Import required packages
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from pylab import cm

df = pd.read_excel("Chlorophyll_data_mod.xlsx")
#----Calculation of meanvalues and sem from raw_data---------
meandf2 = df.set_index(["Group"])
sets = []
for x in ["A","B","AB","xc"]:
    meandf3 = meandf2.filter(like=f"Chl_{x}_").reset_index()
    sets.append(meandf3)
#---------Grouping DataFrame----------#
means = []
ster = []
for x in range(len(sets)):
    meandf = sets[x].groupby(["Group"]).mean()
    meandf = meandf.reset_index()
    means.append(meandf)
    sems = sets[x].groupby("Group").sem()
    sems = sems.reset_index()
    ster.append(sems)
#----Selecting Dataframe from List-----#
plotdf = means[0]
ploter = ster[0]
plotgroup = plotdf.iloc[:,[0,]]
plotdata = plotdf.iloc[:,[1,]]

grouparray = plotgroup.to_numpy()
dataarray = plotdata.to_numpy()

#-----CreatePlot------#
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=3, ncols=1, sharex="all", figsize=(10,8))
plotdf.plot(ax=ax[0,],x="Group",y="Chl_A_0D", kind="bar", legend=False, color="black")
plt.errorbar(x=plotdf["Group"], y=plotdf["Chl_A_0D"],yerr=ploter["Chl_A_0D"])

plotdf.plot(ax=ax[1,],x="Group",y="Chl_A_10DaT", kind="bar", legend=False, color="blue")
plt.errorbar(x=plotdf["Group"], y=plotdf["Chl_A_10DaT"],yerr=ploter["Chl_A_10DaT"])

plotdf.plot(ax=ax[2,],x="Group",y="Chl_A_7DaR", kind="bar", legend=False, color="magenta")
plt.errorbar(x=plotdf["Group"], y=plotdf["Chl_A_7DaR"],yerr=ploter["Chl_A_7DaR"])
#----Legend of the Plot-----#
fig.legend(loc="lower center", bbox_to_anchor=(0.5,0), fancybox=True, ncol=6)

#----Layout------#
plt.tight_layout(rect=[0, 0.02, 1,1])


plt.show()
```

And I manage to create a subplot, which shows 3 of my interested data points. However, I struggle with the error bars.

My approach was to calculate the sem and store it into a new dataframe. And then just read it from there for the yerr. However, this doesn't work.

```
plotdf.plot(ax=ax[2,],x="Group",y="Chl_A_7DaR", kind="bar", legend=False, color="magenta", yerr=ploter["Chl_A_7DaR"])
```

Results in an array error because of the structure.

And my current approach, as in the main code above only draws the error bars in the last subplot, but not in each individual plot.

Maybe here is someone who could help me understanding this function?

Best regards

Comment: `ax[1,].errorbar(....)` should work to put in the middle axes (etc).   In general, you should avoid using `plt.` name space as soon as a plot becomes marginally complicated: https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/api_interfaces.html

Comment: @JodyKlymak Thank you, Sir, I feel blatantly stupid now since this worked. And strangely I tried something like that before, but it didn't work. Anyway, thank you very much for that input!